# When is $A^{-1}\approx A$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I feel this should be an easy one, but cannot resolve it either way.

Let $G$ be a finite group, and suppose that $H$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$, and that $g$ is an element of $G$.  Write $A:=gH$ and $A^{-1}:=Hg^{-1}$.  Is it possible that $|A\setminus A^{-1}|=1$?  How small can $|A\setminus A^{-1}|$ be given that $A\ne A^{-1}$?

If $G$ is abelian, then $A^{-1}=g^{-1}H$ implying $A\setminus A^{-1}=gH\setminus g^{-1}H$. It follows that either $A\setminus A^{-1}=\varnothing$, or $A\setminus A^{-1}=gH$. Therefore, $|A\setminus A^{-1}|\ne 1$; indeed, $|A\setminus A^{-1}|\ge |H|$ unless $A=A^{-1}$.
What about $G$ nonabelian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of bigger picture is behind the problem, but it's pretty easy to come up with an example without further constraint. The strategy is to construct a subgroup $H$ of order $2$, and $g\in G\setminus H$ also of order $2$, then $gH$ and $Hg^{-1}=Hg$ both contains $g$ and have two elements, and we just have to be sure $gH\not=Hg$. This can be easily realized.

Let $G=S_3$, $H=\{(1), (12)\}$, then $$(13)H=\{(13), (123)\}$$ $$H(13)^{-1}=H(13)=\{(13), (132)\}$$

Comment: Is this an answer to the question "Can $|A\setminus A^{-1} | = 1$ ?" If so, did you interpret the $\setminus$ as a set difference or a quotient?

Comment: Yes this is to establish $|A\setminus A^{-1}|=1$ is possible. $\setminus$ means set difference (as its latex operator name suggests), and I don't see any way to interpret this as a quotient in this context.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread $(123)$ and $(132)$ as the same, hence the confusion

Comment: I see. We don't really have to do the calculation. We know that $H$ is not normal as all transpositions are conjugate to each other. Since $|S_3|=6, |H|=2$, the normalizer subgroup of $H$ can only be itself, since there is no subgroup $H'$ with $H<H'<G$. So $gHg^{-1}\not=H$ for any $g\not\in H$.

Comment: This definitely answers my question, as stated (and I will accept your answer) - but, when it comes to the "bigger picture", the case where $|H|=2$ is "special" since in this case $A$ differs from $A^{-1}$ by half the number of elements of $H$. I can easily avoid this situation and assume that $|H|\ge 3$. Can you say anything in this case?

Comment: @W-t-P Interesting... I tried a bit and couldn't find any  solution when $|H|\ge 3$. Maybe there is a case to be made. I'll think a bit more later.

Comment: I found meantime a paper by Olson (On the symmetric difference of two sets in a group, European J. Combin.7(1986), no.1, 43–54) which seems to answer my question - I have to check more carefully.